# Log directories that users go to

Tags: linux, logs, directory

Is there any way to log the directories that a user goes to?

For example as soon as the user **jack** goes to `/home/jack/music/` there is a log that shows he went to `/home/jack/music/`.

Comment: depends on what you mean with "go to"... capturing just the `chdir()` system call (the `cd` command) wouldn't catch e.g. someone just running `ls /home/jack/music/` or `cp /home/jack/music/foo.mp3 somewhere`

Comment: @ilkkachu I mean if the user type ```cd /home/jack/music/``` and hit ENTER this action be captured (logged) in a file or in process like ps aux. I'm writing a tool and need to be notified when a user goes to a specific directory just by typing ```cd /the/specific/directory/```

Comment: You may be interested in `inotify` tools or maybe rather `audit`.

Comment: "A user" doesn't do a "`cd`". One of a user's processes does a "`cd`". A user can have multiple processes running.